# Shell command not working via exec() in php

Tags: php, exec

I'm executing a php function via the PHP `exec()` function but it seems to only pass through 1 variable at time.

```
$url = "http://domain.co/test.php?phone=123&msg=testing"
exec('wget '.$url);
```

Within test.php file I have

```
$msg = "msg =".$_GET["msg"]." number=".$_GET["phone"];
mail('me@gmail.com', 'Working?', $msg);
```

I get an email which returns phone variable only.

But if I change the url as follows

```
$url = "http://domain.co/test.php?msg=testing&phone=123"
```

I get `msg` but not `phone`? Any ideas on what is causing this strange behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `&` sign is a special character in the Unix shell.  You need to escape it:

```
exec("wget '$url'");
```

Also, if your URL is based on user input in any way, be very careful to escape it with [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).  Otherwise your users will be able to run arbitrary Unix commands on your server.

Answer (score 1):

```
$url = "http://domain.co/test.php?phone=123&msg=testing"
exec('wget "'.$url.'"');
```

you need to qoute the url

---

& is the sign for putting a task into background